# AngularJS: Using ng-if to load only necessary DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom

My page loads the content of a category via an AJAX call when the head is clicked. Right now, I am using ng-show to show only the current category:

```
<h3 ng-click="loadFood('food1')" id="food1">Food 1</h3>   
 <div class="food origin">
        <food-list ng-show="category == 'food1' " />
 </div>

<h3 ng-click="loadFood('food2')" id="food2">Food 2</h3>
    <div class="food origin">
         <food-list  ng-show="category == 'food2' " />
   </div>
```

This loads the content of the current category into all the food lists, but hides the inactive ones- so the DOM is still huge, which is what I am trying to avoid.

I want to use ng-if instead, which is supposed to add & remove items from the DOM tree. But I can't get any ng-if statements to work. If I directly swap the ng-show for an ng-if, like so:

```
 <h3 ng-click="loadFood('food2')" id="food2">Food 2</h3>

    <div class="food origin">
         <food-list  ng-if="category == 'food2' " />
</div>
```

Then I get the contents of the current category loaded into all of the food origin divs, and all categories are all shown.

What is the best way to rework this so that only the content of the currently active category is loaded into the DOM at one time?

[Here's my Plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/STtV1ORclknwriXZgMR4?p=preview)

## UPDATE

Version issue. Was using 1.0.8, ng-if wasn't added til later. Updated Angular version to 1.2. Ng-if is now working in principle, but always returning false. Next step, getting ng-if statement to == true.

Comment: your plunker throws errors if you click on a food header.

Comment: Yep, broken slider plug-in was breaking the ng-if statement. Removing the slider plug-in fixed it, is now working as it's meant to.