# Should not display empty and undefined values when using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am looping through the JSON to display values Company name and divisions under it , but the issue is that how can i stop to display division names for whose company name is empty

This is my code

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
   <div class="box-footer no-padding">
      <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
         <li ng-repeat="item in tickets" ng-if="item.name!='' && item.name">
            <a class="clearfix">
            {{item.name}}
            <span ng-repeat="form in item.forms" class="pull-right badge ml5" >{{form.name}}</span>
            </a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can i tried using `ng-if="item.name!='' && item.name"`

I don't want to display the divisions if the company name is empty or undefined .

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/416/

Comment: I suggest you can make a filter based on name values

Comment: @Pawan I saw you already accept an answer, but I really suggest you to read [**this one**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43610952/4927984), that explain how to keep using ng-if (avoiding DOM elements creating in ng-repeating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.name` is not a boolean so you could just use `ng-show` without second condition.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in tickets" ng-show="item.name!=''">
   <a class="clearfix">{{item.name}}
     <span ng-repeat="form in item.forms" class="pull-right badge ml5" >{{form.name}}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

**[Your Forked Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/8pyphnc7/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your Fiddle may not work because you are using **Angular 1.0.1** [which has some issue in `ng-if`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726148/angularjs-using-ng-if-to-load-only-necessary-dom-elements). If you are really using this version, you can replace `ng-if` by `ng-show` (which will create hidden elements in the DOM).

Anyway, the best solution would be to use **Angular 1.2+** which fixes `ng-if` bugs in `ng-repeat`. As you can see in the following snippet, I didn't change your code, and it works.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.tickets = [{

    "name": "",
    "forms": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "HR",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "role": "primary"
    }]
  }, {

    "name": "TCS",
    "forms": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "DEV",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "role": "primary"
    }, {
      "name": "HR",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "role": "primary"
    }]
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"/>

<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
  <div class="box-footer no-padding">
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
      <li ng-repeat="item in tickets" ng-if="item.name != '' && item.name">
        <a class="clearfix">
          {{item.name}}
          <span ng-repeat="form in item.forms" class="pull-right badge ml5" >{{form.name}}</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Forked your Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/9f97ayyo/)** (just changed Angular version).